# Is using Task.Run a bad practice?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

Generally, when implementing an asynchronous method on a class, I write something like this:

```
public Task<Guid> GetMyObjectIdAsync(string objectName)
{
    return Task.Run(() => GetMyObjectId(objectName));
}

private Guid GetMyObjectId(string objectName)
{
    using (var unitOfWork = _myUnitOfWorkFactory.CreateUnitOfWork())
    {
        var myObject = unitOfWork.MyObjects.Single(o => o.Name == objectName);
        return myObject.Id;
    }
}
```

This sort of pattern allows me to use the same logic synchronously and asynchronously, depending on the situation (most of my work is in an old code base, not a lot supports async calls yet), as I could expose the synchronous method publicly and get maximum compatibility if I need to.

Recently I've read several SO posts that suggest using `Task.Run()` is a bad idea, and should only be used under certain circumstances, but those circumstances did not seem very clear.

Is the pattern I've depicted above actually a bad idea?  Am I losing some of the functionality/ intended purpose of async calls doing it this way?  Or is this a legit implementation?

Comment: Why don't you link those mysterious SO posts? I mean they should already contain your answer, right?

Comment: No basically, they're always mentioning "You shouldn't be using Task.Run()" as a kind of throwaway comment... but I've seen it enough to make me worry that I might be doing it wrong.

Comment: https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Three-Essential-Tips-for-Async/Async-Library-Methods-Shouldn-t-Lie

Comment: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What you are doing is offloading a synchronous operation to another thread. If your thread is "special" then that's perfectly fine. One example of a "special" thread is a UI thread. In that case you may want to offload work off of it to keep the UI responsive (another example is some kind of listener).

In most cases, however, you're just moving work around from one thread to another. This doesn't add any value and does add unnecessary overhead.

So:

> Is the pattern I've depicted above actually a bad idea?

Yes, it is. It's a bad idea to offload synchronous work to the `ThreadPool` and pretend as if it's asynchronous.

> Am I losing some of the functionality/ intended purpose of async calls doing it this way?

There's actually nothing asynchronous about this operation to begin with. If you're executing this on a remote machine and you can benefit from doing it asynchronously the operation itself needs to be truly asynchronous, meaning:

```
var myObject = await unitOfWork.MyObjects.SingleAsync(o => o.Name == objectName);
```

What you're currently doing is called "async over sync" and you probably shouldn't do it. More in [Should I expose asynchronous wrappers for synchronous methods?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/)

Comment: So, what _is_ the difference being "asynchronous code" and "synchronous code run on the ThreadPool"? Isn't it turtles all the way down?

Comment: So if I understand correctly, this is not allowing it to run asynchronously, just allowing it to fit in the async framework?  Is that an accurate statement?

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs you're creating a `Task`. The framework you're using is the TPL (Task Parallel Library). It came before async-await and "lives below it". You're async-adjacent but there's nothing truly asynchronous here.

Comment: @CodeCaster asynchronous code is code that is implemented to be asynchronous. It's mostly I/O and it requires support for asynchronous operations from the OS. You can read more here: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html

Comment: @i3arnon so basicly everything runs *syncronous* in another *Thread* which may be called *asynchronous*? So IMHO the Question is "Why would i run code asynchronous?" and If so "Which structure shall I use to make my code efficient, maintainable and stuff?" 
-
Cool Answer btw :)

Comment: @i3arnon: I think though, in the OP's case, he's working with an existing codebase, so this is an exception to the rule. Would hate to tell him "you need to refactor and regress **everything** in order to be pure"...

Comment: @LuckyLikey truly asynchronous operations are operations that don't require running code. For example sending a request over the wire may start synchronously but at some point the hardware take over and the CPU doesn't need to execute any other operation.

Comment: @code4life no, this is not an exception. There's no point in adding that method. OP may choose to refactor everything, or just some paths of code. But adding that method is simply unnecessary.

Comment: This might be slightly tangential, but could you explain the difference between wrapping a Task.Run and a .SingleAsync() invocation?

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs by `SingleAsync` I mean an async API provided by some kind of data store. If `MyObjects` is just a list in memory there's no async operation necessary, just filter it synchronously as it's all CPU bound work. When operations aren't CPU bound (i.e. They don't need CPU to execute) you can initiate them and await their completion asynchronously. For example if this `SingleAsync` calls a database and returns a result there's no CPU instructions to execute in the mean time. That's where async comes in handy.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs so if the operation is synchronous using `Task.Run` just means a different thread will run it. If it's asynchronous then it would already return a `Task` and `Task.Run` would be unnecessary.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Asynchronous code is any code where (1) you ask for a computation, (2) the computation is going to take some time for some reason, (3) while you are waiting, you run other code on this thread, (4) when the result is available, you consume the result.  One way to achieve asynchrony is to move work onto other threads, but there is no *requirement* that asynchrony be achieved this way. Any more than there is a requirement that you hire one cook for the eggs and one cook for the toast when you are making breakfast.

Answer (score 13):

> Recently I've read several SO posts that suggest using Task.Run() is a bad idea, and should only be used under certain circumstances, but those circumstances did not seem very clear.

The absolutely bare bones rules of thumb I tell people who are new to asynchrony is:

First, understand the purpose. **Asynchrony is for mitigating the important inefficiencies of high-latency operations.**

Is the thing you're doing low-latency? Then don't make it asynchronous in any way.  Just do the work. It's fast. Using a tool to mitigate latency on low-latency tasks is just making your program unnecessarily complex.

Is the thing you're doing high-latency because it is waiting on a disk to spin or a packet to show up?  Make this asynchronous but *do not put it on another thread*. You don't hire a worker to sit by your mailbox waiting for letters to arrive; the postal system is already running asynchronously to you.  You don't need to hire people to make it more asynchronous.  Read "[There Is No Thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html)" if that's not clear.

Is the high-latency work waiting on a CPU to do some enormous computation? Like a computation that is going to take well over 10 ms? Then offload that task onto a thread so that the thread can be scheduled to an idle CPU.

Comment: From your comment, _Make this asynchronous but do not put it on another thread_, I gather that the snippet I provided above is the exact opposite?  Can you provide an example of how I would make it asynchrounous but keep it on the same thread?

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs: You make something asynchronous but not multithreaded by (1) yielding control back to the caller at the point where the high latency operation begins, and (2) remembering what work needs to be done when the operation completes - that is, the *continuation* - and (3) detecting when the operation completes and scheduling the continuation to run. As for how you know when the operation completes, well, that depends on the operation doesn't it? You would know better than I would when your operation completes.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs: In your particular case I don't know what the slow thing is that you are attempting to make asynchronous. Is it the creation of the unit of work, the fetching of the object set, fetching the name, filtering of the object set or the production of the identifier which could take more than 30 ms?  Whichever it is, that's the thing you should be concentrating on making asynchronous.

Comment: Hmm, OK, thanks.  I'm glad I asked this question now, it seems a lot of my suppositions were incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

```
public Task<Guid> GetMyObjectIdAsync(string objectName)
```

When I see this, I expect there to be some advantage in using this method rather than just wrapping it in `Task.Run()` myself.

In particular, I'd expect it to release the thread when it hits some I/O or otherwise has the opportunity to do so.

Now consider if I have the code:

```
_resource = GetResourceForID(GetMyObjectIdAsync(SomeLongRunningWayToGetName()));
```

If I have a reason to need to have this done in a task, and I'm in the sort of situation where `Task.Run()` does actually make sense (I have a reason to offload it onto another thread) the best way to do this would be to wrap the whole thing:

```
Task task = Task.Run(() => _resource = GetResourceForID(GetMyObjectIdAsync(SomeLongRunningWayToGetName())));
```

Here `Task.Run()` **might** be a bad idea **for me as the caller**, or it might be good because I really am gaining from what it gives me.

However, if I see your signature I'm going to *think* that the best way to do this with your code would be to turn it into code that uses that method.

```
Task task = SomeLongRunningWayToGetName()
  .ContinueWith(t => GetMyObjectIdAsync(t.Result))
  .ContinueWith(t => _resource = GetResourceForIDAsync(t.Result));
```

(Or similar using `async` and `await`).

At best this has less good chunking of the `Task.Run()`. At worse I'm `await`ing this just to gain from the better asynchronicity that it doesn't offer in a context that could make use of it if it was really there. (E.g I might have used this in an MVC action that I'd made asynchronous because I thought the extra overhead would be repaid in better thread-pool use).

So while `Task.Run()` is sometimes useful, in this case it's always bad. If you can't offer me greater asynchronicity than I can bring to the use of the class myself, don't lead me to believe you do.

Only offer a public `XXXAsync()` method if it really does call into asynchronous I/O.

If you **really need** to stub out an asynchronous method to e.g. match a signature of a shared base or interface, then it would be better as:

```
public Task<Guid> GetMyObjectIdAsync(string objectName)
{
  return Task.FromResult(GetMyObjectId(objectName);
}
```

This is bad too (the caller would still have been better off just calling `GetMyObjectId()` directly), but at least if code `await`s it then while it operates on the same thread there's no overhead of using yet another thread to do the work, so if it's mixed in with other `await`s the negative impact is reduced. It's therefore useful if you **really** need to return a `Task` but can't add anything useful in how you call it.

But if you don't **really** need to offer it, just don't.

(A private method calling `Run()` because you every call site benefits from it is different, and there you're just adding convenience rather than calling `Run()` in several places, but that should be well-documented as such).